# Why is only one cookie saved when live?

Tags: php, ajax, cookies

I have a php script handling an incoming ajax request. It looks up some credentials from text files and if they match requirements it sets two cookies, one called username and one called creds on the client machine.

When I do this from my local web server, all three cookies get set and I receive all the php feedback from the echoes.

When I do this from my hosted web server the first setcookie works ("cookies","enabled") but the next two dont! However I get all the echoes confirming that php has reached the point in my script where they should be set. Any ideas please? I am thoroughly stumped.

```
<?php

  //george:bloog
  //emeline:sparg


  setCookie("primacy[cookies]","enabled", time()+3600*24*30,'/');


  //convert string to summed int
  function pwdInt($pw)
  {
    $pwdIntVal = 0;

    for($i=0; $i<strlen($pw);$i++)
    {
      $pwdIntVal = $pwdIntVal + ( ord(strtolower($pw[$i])) - 96 );
    }

    return $pwdIntVal;
  }

  //retrieve user account creation date by parsing savefile for accountCreate var
  function getACD($aUSR)
  {
    $saveFileName = "saveFiles/" . $aUSR . ".txt";

    echo "Fetched save successfully.<br>";

    $lines = file($saveFileName);
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
      if( explode(":",$line)[0] == "accountCreate");
      $lineDate = explode(":",$line)[1];
      return $lineDate;
    }
  }




  //accept incoming vars
  if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']))
  {
      $uN = strtolower($_POST['username']);
      $pwd = strtolower($_POST['password']);
      $found = "Invalid user";


      //test for presence in creds
      $lines = file("creds/creds.txt");
      foreach($lines as $line)
      {
          $lineName = explode("_",$line)[0];
          if($uN == $lineName)
          {
            //matched username before delimiter "_"
            $found = $lineName;
            echo "Found user, " .  explode("_",$line)[0] . " checking     password<br>";

            //check two: use int of pwd with account creation date from user save
            $usrACD = getACD($uN);
            echo $usrACD;

            if(  (pwdInt($pwd) * $usrACD) ==  (explode("_",$line)[1])  )
            {
              echo "Tests passed: granting access cookies";
              setCookie("uN",$uN, time()+3600*24*30,'/');
              setCookie("cred",(pwdInt($pwd) * $usrACD),     time()+3600*24*30,'/');
            }
            else
            {
              echo "Failed password check for allowed user<br>";
            }
          }
      }
  }
  else
  {
    echo $found . pwdInt($pwd) . "<br>";
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either enable output buffering or move echoes after `setCookie` method. Setting cookies is thing that happens during headers of response. All headers should be sent before content. Echoing things is setting up content, so every header edition (like setting cookies) after first echo will fail.

Comment: I read that the most common cause was setting cookies after header responses. I must not be understanding the timing of the ajax call correctly. I'll try without the echoes and see if it is working. Can you think why this isn't a problem on my local machine?

Comment: You have probably enabled output buffering in your configuration. It awaits all your content (echoes in this case) and buffer it to avoid sending it before headers, so you are able to set new headers all along the script. When script is finishing it execution, it sends all collected headers and afterwards, your buffer.

Comment: You were right! I need to go and read more about how echo timing works. Thanks very much.